# Batch file basics: Adding a hardcoded integer to a variable in a for loop

Tags: file, math, batch-file, for-loop

I want to simply add 10 to the variable "%%i" in this batch file code and print it out to the screen. numbers.txt is a file that contains a single column of numbers.

```
FOR /F %%i IN (numbers.txt) DO (
    set /a "T=%%i+10"
    @echo %T%
)
```

For example, if %%i was 1 I would want T to be 11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without delayed expansion, you can use:

```
@echo off
set constant=10
FOR /F %%i IN (numbers.txt) DO (
    set /a "T=%%i+%constant%"
    call echo %%T%%
)
```

constant does not need delayed expansion, because it's constant throughout the loop.

Comment: Not a good idea to use `TEMP` as a batchfile variable - it points to a directory used for temporary files...(`TMP` too)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it should work according to your description in the question :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set T=0  
set K=10
for /f %%i in (numbers.txt) do (    
  set /A T=!K! + %%i    
  echo !T! )
endlocal
```

Save it as a .bat file extension and run from command prompt.
If file *numbers.txt* contain :

```
1
2
3
```

Output will be:

```
11
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with delayed environment variable expansion. In the shell, you must first type

```
cmd /v
```

Then you can execute this batch script:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (numbers.txt) DO (
    set /a T=%%i + 10
    @echo !T!
)
```

If you don't run `cmd /v` first, then it will simply output `!T!` literally. See `set /?` for details on delayed environment variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Start your batch file by turning on delayed expansion.  With delayed expansion enabled, reference a variable inside a loop using `!` instead of `%`.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%i IN (numbers.txt) DO (
    set /a "T=%%i+10"
    @echo !T!
)
```